# How to define a new counter in the tasks package?

Tags: counters, tasks

I want to use the `tasks` package,
and I want to use `mynum` (my alphabet enumerate) to enumerate tasks.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,tasks}

\makeatletter
\def\@mynum#1{\ifcase#1\or آ\or ب\or پ\or ت\or ث\or
    ج\or چ\or ح\or خ\or د\or ذ\or ر\or ز\or ژ\or س\or ش\or ص\or ض\or ط\or ظ\or ع\or غ\or ف\or ق\or ک\or گ\or ل\or م\or ن\or و\or هـ\or ی\else \@ctrerr\fi}
\def\mynum#1{\expandafter\@mynum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[1])](4)
\task
aaa
\task
bbb
\task
ccc
\task
ddd
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be easier if one would understand the figures there. What is `\@myharfi` doing?

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer. thanks. 
that is my type wrong. corect is \@mynum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a new counter but a new representation. The shortcut from the tasks package are defined in the cntformats package, and its documentation describes how to add new ones:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}

\makeatletter
\def\@mynum#1{\ifcase#1\or X\or Y\or Z\else ?\fi}
\NewPatternFormat{m}{\@mynum}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[m])](4)
\task
aaa
\task
bbb
\task
ccc
\task
ddd
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]